# Python regular exp to stop greediness from extending beyond one line

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

```
Name is A, Last:B
Last Login: 10 min
```

I want to extract the name and the last login time only

When I use the regex as below

```
 Name is ([A-Z])[\s\w,:]+
```

it became greedy and matched the whole string so I cannot extract the Last login time (10 min) . How do I stop the greediness from extending beyond one line

Any help towards this please

Comment: Please show us the expected output.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to extract the "last login" time separately? Why not extract it within the same regex? `Name is ([A-Z])[\s\w,:]+Last Login: (.*)` should work. The reason why your regex matches so much is that `\s` also matches newlines. You can use that to your advantage.

Comment: Do you want [`Name is ([A-Z][, \w:]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/LQl5Tt/1)? `\s` matches line breaks, you may use a simple space if you need to match just simple `\u0020` spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
>>> print s
Name is A, Last:B
Last Login: 10 min
```

You can use `re.search` with the `re.M` multiline flag to capture that pattern:

```
>>> re.search(r"^(Name is[^,]*).*\s*(^Last Login:.*)",s,re.M).groups()
('Name is A', 'Last Login: 10 min')
```

Or if you just want that data after the fixed fields:

```
>>> re.search(r"^Name is\s*([^,]*).*\s*^Last Login:\s*(.*)",s,re.M).groups()
('A', '10 min')
```

Alternatively, you can use look behinds to see the fields your want and then capture what follows:

```
>>> re.search(r"(?<=Name is)\s*([^,]*),.*\n.*(?<=Last Login:)\s*(.*)",s).groups()
('A', '10 min')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.search`

**Demo:**

```
import re
s = """Name is A, Last:B
Last Login: 10 min"""

name = re.search("Name is (?P<name>\w+)", s)
if name:
    print(name.group('name'))

ll = re.search("Last Login: (?P<lastLogin>.*)", s)
if ll:
    print(ll.group('lastLogin'))
```

**Output:**

```
A
10 min
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what are you trying to avoid with `[\s\w,:]+` but you can just use `"Name is ([A-Z]\w*), Last:([A-Z]\w*)\nLast Login: (\d+)"`:

```
>>> re.match(r"Name is ([A-Z]\w*), Last:([A-Z]\w*)\nLast Login: (\d+)",
...          'Name is A, Last:B\nLast Login: 10 min').groups()
('A', 'B', '10')
```

As long as `re.dotall` is not activated, you can use `.+` and it won't match newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches the whole example because the [`\s`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) in your character class also matches newlines.

Another way to match your value is to use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|` to match either:

- `^Name is ([A-Z])` Match from the start `^` of the line `Name is` and capture a single uppercase character in a group `([A-Z])`. If you want to match more than one you could use a quantifier for the character class.
- `|` or
- `^Last Login: ([\w ]+)` Match from the start `^` of the line `Last Login:` and capture in a group one or more times a word character or a whitespace `([\w ]+)`. If you want to match any character you could also use `(.*)`

[`^Name is ([A-Z])|^Last Login: ([\w ]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/vucQkm/1)

Your values will be in capturing group 1 and capturing group 2.